# Drawing a set of points taking into account the strength of their friendship

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have an n-by-n symmtric matrix F of non-negative integers: F[i,j] is a measure of how close the guys i and j are. I want to locate n points in the plane representing the n guys in such a way that

- two guys which are close are represented by points which are close and,
- ideally, two guys which are not that close and which are not even connected by a chain of close friendships are represented by points which are far away.

Is there a standard algorithm to do this?

Comment: I tried using neato and fdp with edges with weights computed as F[i,j]^2/ and similar formulas, and the resulting graphs are not very help full.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is generically referred to as multi-dimensional scaling (MDS) or Principal Coordinates Analysis (PCA--but be aware that there are other techniques also known as PCA).

There are quite a few well-known algorithms for carrying out MDS. That's mostly because the classical methods are pretty slow--O(N<sup>2</sup>). Most others are attempts at reducing the run-time while minimizing loss of accuracy.

At least in my experience, Landmark multidimensional scaling (LMDS) maintains pretty close to the accuracy of full MDS, but reduces run-time substantially. The basic idea here is to compute MDS on sub-groups of the points, the compute a way to fit the pieces together.

If you really want maximum speed, and don't care a whole lot about accuracy, you could consider the FastMap algorithm.

For what it's worth: what I've generally found most useful is to reduce the raw data to around 17-21 degrees of freedom using LMDS, then (if you want to display the results) reduce from there to 3 or 2 dimensions using FastMap. I haven't used the full MDS much, but if you're working with few enough points for it to be practical, it's generally the preferred solution.

Here are a few relevant links:

1. [MDS](http://forrest.psych.unc.edu/teaching/p208a/mds/mds.html)
2. [LMDS](http://window.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-05-winter/Papers/Landmarks/Silva_landmarks5.pdf)
3. [FastMap](http://www.cs.bu.edu/faculty/gkollios/ada02/LectNotes/P163.PDF)

Comment: Thanks! My matrices are not that large: n is close to 100.

Comment: @Mariano: For 100 items, full MDS is probably your first choice.

Comment: There is a circle in hell reserved for those who write things like «In this article we use the term similarity generically to refer to both similarities (where large numbers refer to great similarity) and to dissimilarities (where large numbers refer to great dissimilarity).»